# Custom function to compute contrasts in emmeans

Tags: r, emmeans

I want to create a custom contrast function in emmeans which could remove a given list of levels from the input vector and apply the built-in contrast method ("trt.vs.ctrl") on the remaining levels. An example dataset is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yszq7wwmno6qdfo/example.csv?dl=0). I am using the following R code for computing ANOVA and post hoc comparisons:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
my_lm <- lm(D1 ~ C*R, data=df)
Anova(my_lm, type = "III")
#show Interaction effects using emmeans
emmip(my_lm, C ~ R )
emm = emmeans(my_lm, ~ C * R)
emm
contrast(emmeans(my_lm, ~ C * R), "consec", by = "C")
#compare 1st with next 3 groups (how to remove other three levels?)
contrast(emmeans(my_lm, ~ C * R), "trt.vs.ctrl", by = "R")
```

The built-in contrast option ("trt.vs.ctrl") compares the first level with everything that follows it (there are 7 factor levels in C, and I want to remove last 3 of them and compute the contrasts for the remaining 4). [An example is provided in the official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#linfcns) to write a custom contrast function.

```
skip_comp.emmc <- function(levels, skip = 1, reverse = FALSE) {
    if((k <- length(levels)) < skip + 1)
        stop("Need at least ", skip + 1, " levels")
    coef <- data.frame()
    coef <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq_len(k - skip - 1), function(i) {
        sgn <- ifelse(reverse, -1, 1)
        sgn * c(rep(0, i - 1), 1, rep(0, skip), -1, rep(0, k - i - skip - 1))
    }))
    names(coef) <- sapply(coef, function(x)
        paste(which(x == 1), "-", which(x == -1)))
    attr(coef, "adjust") = "fdr"   # default adjustment method
    coef
}
```

However due to my limited understanding I am not very sure where to apply the modifications that I need to to customise the example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you are going to want to do lots of times in the future? My guess is not, that you only want to do this once, or a few times at most; in  which case it is way too much trouble to write a custom contrast function. Just get the contrast coefficients you need, and use that as the second argument in `contrast`.

Now, consider these results:

```
> con <- emmeans:::trt.vs.ctrl.emmc(1:7)
> con
  2 - 1 3 - 1 4 - 1 5 - 1 6 - 1 7 - 1
1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
2     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     0     0     0     0
4     0     0     1     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     1     0     0
6     0     0     0     0     1     0
7     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

From the description, I think you just want the first 3 sets of contrast coefficients. So use those columns:

```
contrast(emm, con[, 1:3], by = "R")
```

#### Update

StackOverflow can occasionally inspire developers to add software features. In this case, I decided it could be useful to add an `exclude` argument to most built-in `.emmc` functions in **emmeans** (all except `poly.emmc()`). This was fairly straightforward to do, and those features are now incorporated in the latest push to github -- https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans. These features will be included in the next CRAN update as well.

Comment: Thanks. It works with rearranging the group sequence.

Comment: You can cover all possibilities by choosing `ref` and `reverse` arguments for `trt.vs.ctrl.emmc()`, and varying which columns to pick out.

Comment: I hope it will be beneficial for someone. I am interested in nonparametric comparisons now (having realized my data violates assumptions of normality). There aren't many options for nonparametric tests (certainly no equivalent of emmeans to control group comparisons whatsoever). So it is fishing for relevant comparisons after running post hoc (dunn.test).